# Realizar consulta Httpclient Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Estoy realizando una consulta especifica a un valor, tengo un grupo de articulos y quiero ver solo un articulo.

Viendo el manual de Cakephp me muestra esto pero no se como usarlo.

```
$response = $http->post('http://example.com/api', http_build_query([
    'search' => $this->request->getData('search'),
]));
```

Comment: lo que basicamente te dice es que estas pidiendo a la url (http://example.com/api) realizar una busqueda con el parametro (search)

Comment: gracias por su respuesta, para el parametro (search)  que habla quiero es que me traiga un articulo no todos.

Comment: en efecto para eso debes saber que metodo trae un registro.. conocer la url y que parametro psar es decir un id/nombre/codigo...etc.. para que consulte bajo ese parametro tu articulo....

Comment: la url  es http://localhost/paginaconsumows/consu-articles/view/53

Comment: para ello usa el metodo get como te muestro en mi respuesta..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejare una breve explicacion:
primero que nada debes instanciar la clase **HttpClient** algo asi:

```
use Cake\Http\Client; 
$http = new Client();
```

Ahora debemos saber que metodo vamos a consumir:

- GET
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE .. ETC..

EJEMPLO GET(traer una consulta):

```
$response = $http->get('http://ejemplo.com/search', ['id' => '1001']);
```

en este breve ejemplo consulto un articulo/producto por id, puede ser id, nombre, codigo, etc... ya depende como se establecio el servicio que vas a consumir.
EJEMPLO POST(agregar/insertar data):

```
$response = $http->post('http://ejemplo.com/articulos/add', [
  'codigo' => 'art-505',
  'nombre' => 'Iphone 6 16gb'
]);
```

en este caso es el metodo POST , que envio como parametros codigo y nombre al servicio en response tengo el resultado de mi metodo. sea de error o sactisfactorio.

y asi.. deberias intentar con los metodos deseados y ver que resultados trae.

**Espero te sirva de guia !!**

Comment: yo tengo mi metodo asi 'public function View($id  = null)
 {
 
 $jsondata = ['id'=>$id];
 $http = new Client();
 $response = $http->get('http://localhost/paginaws/articles/index.json',['id' =>'53']);
 $json = $response->body;
 $valor = json_decode($json);
 
 var_dump($valor);

 }'